# Degree of odd mapping of sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Is it possible to prove the fact that every smooth odd mapping of $S^n$ (such that $f(x)=-f(-x)$ for every $x$) has odd degree using  formula which connects degree and number of preimages of regular value of such mappings? (i.e. $$\deg f=\sum\limits_{f(x)=y}\operatorname{sign}\det\,df|_{x}$$ where $y$ is a regular value).

Comment: isn't the identity function "odd" under this definition?

Comment: @Timkinsella Yes, it is, but it has odd degree so nothing bad happens

Comment: Do you know for sure this is true? Is it a textbook exercise?

Comment: @Timkinsella This fact is equivalent to Borsuk-Ulam theorem but I'm wondering about it's direct proof.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best proof in that line is Alexandroff-Hopf, which can be read in Dieudonné's *A history of algebraic and differential geometry* (Part 2, Chapter 1, Section 4, pp.180-181).